# JavaScript in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I was wondering how i would go about implementing JS into my SharePoint online master page.  Is the best way to have a separate file with JS functions that is stored in the site contents and then referenced by the Masterpage somehow? if so how would i go about referencing it.  And if not how else could I go about doing this?

Comment: I assume you're talking straight classic experience? There are no master pages with the new Modern experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best and simple way is to create a **JS folder** in your **Style Library** under **Site Contents** in the current site then reference it into your **masterpage** like this : `<script src="https://tenant/yoursite/Style Library/yourProject/js/yourcustomscript.js">` and you can also make modification directly on your file in SharePoint Online and see results instantly.

Comment: Awesome thanks! and I know that there are a lot of sharepoint snippets that are wrapped in a comment that will still get run by the server... Does this line need to be in one of those? for example "<!--SPM:...-->"? or would the reference line be written without this sharepoint comment?

Comment: You can add it directly without "<!--SPM:...-->"